# Testing Microsite Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, css, microsites

I´m creating an order Form, landing pages. In this landing pages, I have a piece of ampscript, to retrieve from the DE, and a piece of javascript, to validate the form, as well some links to css files.

My way for testing is pushing "subscribers preview", but when I do it, I can look at my tag  has changed. I attached a screen shoot.

So, I guess I'm testing in a bad way my microsites inside MC.

Could anyone help me? 
Thank you in advanced.

[image]

Comment: Can you please copy and paste your code in correct formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m answering myself. :)

I had to "publish" the page before being able to access via the URL.
To do that, 
Interaction > Microsites. Here create a new one, and "start" it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the landing pages are retrieved by appending the subscriber key to the pages address for each customer.

So

www.landingpageaddress.com+qs=subscriberkey

Should go to your landing page

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
When I click, the URL I get a page with the following message "The page you have requested is unavailable!"

Do I have to do anything in the properties of the page?